# API key for hosted website

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to display cards similar to the movies app.
I developed a website and hosted it.
By parsing JSON I am getting data into horizontal cards.

how to get the API key for hosted website in order to use in the application?

Answer (score 0):

From [themoviedb FAQ](https://www.themoviedb.org/faq/api):

> You can apply for an API key by clicking the "API" link from the left
>   hand sidebar within your account settings page. You need to have a
>   legitimate business name, address, phone number and description to
>   apply for an API key.

So create an account on themoviedb, get the API key and use it in your website logic.

Comment: Thanks for explaination.                                    My doubt is movies app have used  https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en  this site to get api key. Then how should I get api key for my hosted site in 000webhost.? Already i am using  firebase database for api keys.

Comment: @pravalikanaidu ok you need an api key for your website to get movies from themoviedb?